# Tablayout when long pressing tab item Tool tip is poping

Tags: java, android

I'm using Tablayout and when im pressing long there is pop coming tab item like toast what is this and how should i stop poping?
[image]

This is my tabLayout Xml

```
        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/result_tabs"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="#00B8D4"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="#00B8D4"
            app:tabTextColor="?attr/colorWhite"
            app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"/>
```

i want stop showing that pop

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom `OnLongClickListener` for the tabs and prevent the default behavior like below.

```
TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

// Iterate through all the tabs and set a custom OnLongClickListener for each tab
for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
    View tabView = ((ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(i);

    // Disable the tooltip by setting an empty OnLongClickListener
    tabView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // Return true to consume the event and prevent the default tooltip behavior
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: nope its not working